# Data type not working in Solr

Tags: date, solr, cassandra

I wanna fetch records including a date type from Cassandra in solr, the following are my codes:

```
    in dataconfig.xml:
    <entity name="artist" query="SELECT artist_id, name, email, total_jobs, created FROM artist_list">
    <field column="artist_id" template="ARTIST_${artist.artist_id}" name="id"/>        
    <field column="created" name="artist_created" />
    </entity> 

    in schema.xml:
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="artist_created" type="tdate" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

But the result did not contain created field. Is there anyone can tell me what the problem is? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining tdate data type as solr.TrieDoubleField. That's why result don't contain artist_created data.

Change your schema to :

```
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<field name="artist_created" type="date" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: thanks for ur response. But seems that was not working :(

Comment: @JenniferHe you need to reindex data, every time you change schema

Comment: @Ashrafaul you mean re-import data? :)